# Dealing with an incrementing SNMP OID?

Tags: c#, snmp

I'm trying to use SNMP to get data from a printer. If I turn the printer off and on, the OID that I need to `get` is  `.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.1`. Each time the printer has an "event", such as getting paused, running out of paper or having a paper jam, the OIDfor the data I want increments.

For example, I turn the printer on and query `.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.1.` and I get "paused" as the value. I unpause the printer and remove all of the paper from the printer, and to get the "add paper" message I have to query `.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.2`.

I don't know if this is normal SNMP behavior but I wonder what people suggest I do in these cases to be able to programatically get the printer state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's normal you are retreiving rows from an alert table :

Just have a look to the mib :

[image]

The corresponding text part of the mib is ([from RFC 1759](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1759.html)):

```
prtAlertTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     SEQUENCE OF PrtAlertEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS     current
    DESCRIPTION
        ""
    ::= { prtAlert 1 }

prtAlertEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     PrtAlertEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS     current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Entries may exist in the table for each device
        index who's device type is `printer'."
    INDEX  { hrDeviceIndex, prtAlertIndex }
    ::= { prtAlertTable 1 }

PrtAlertEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
    prtAlertIndex               Integer32,
    prtAlertSeverityLevel       INTEGER,
    prtAlertTrainingLevel       INTEGER,
    prtAlertGroup               INTEGER,
    prtAlertGroupIndex          Integer32,
    prtAlertLocation            Integer32,
    prtAlertCode                INTEGER,
    prtAlertDescription         OCTET STRING,
    prtAlertTime                TimeTicks
}
```

So the way SNMP works is to is to suffix the OID entry of the MIB by the index of the row. You can get the whole table by a Get-Bulk, but I think that the first thing for you is to understand how to retreive an SNMP table.

In your exact case : `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.1` you have to read it as :

`1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8` : prtAlertDescription followed by

`1` : the hrDeviceIndex followed by

`1` : the prtAlertIndex which is the row.

An Advice you can find an assembly called [snmpsharpnet](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/) which is very helpful to play with SNMP on the top of .NET.

Comment: I'm actually using snmpsharp already. The printer only supports SNMP v1 though, does that mean I can't do a GetBulk?

Comment: Yes Get-Bulk is only avaible on SNMPV2c. So you have to program a walk, (a look on get-next) from the first colon

Comment: ok, with that I think it's probably best then to just do a Get in incrementing values until I hit something. Kind of where I started but at least I know there isn't a better option out there.

Comment: I Edit the answer to deserv your vote explaining a bit more the OID you give. But **Sorry**, I do not validate your conclusion in your comment. **PLEASE** read the MIB description of `prtAlertIndex` because you may have supprises (I update the answer for ce RFC link)

Comment: I appreciate your response. I read the description of prtAlertIndex in that RFC. It was useful for me to read about that. It still looks like checking each OID in succession (e.g. 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.1, 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.2, 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.3 etc.) until I find a hit is the only route I can take though because I don't have any access to the prtAlertIndex value (1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.1) for my particular printer. When I try to query that OID I get an error saying "No Such Name".

Comment: @omatase You can't Get the row index, that's not a concept that exists. There is no "current row", just a table with lots of rows in it. Unfortunately you do not know ahead of time how many rows there are. I think you need to do some more reading up about what a table is. There may be other objects in this MIB that give you the "current" or "most recent" state, as well as this historical log.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your printer is storing a list of states. You have to get bulk starting from OID  .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.1 and use the last variable binding from the group.

Comment: Is that equivalent to doing a Get repeatedly while incrementing the final digit of the OID? I hadn't heard of Get Bulk before but in looking into it it sounds like that's what it does under the hood. You provide it a number that represents the max implicit GetNext calls to make and it does that until it finds a value or until it hits the maximum number specified.

Comment: If you are using SNMP v2, get bulk PDU allows to get a bunch of values from a table in one operation. If the table is too big for one datagram, you might need to send several get bulk requests.